# Calculating means of a NumPy array by grouping rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have an m-by-n NumPy array `A`, where each row represents an observation of some data. My rows are also assigned to one of c classes, and the class for each row is stored in an m-by-1 NumPy array `B`. I now want to compute the mean observation data `M` for each class. How can I do this?

For example:

```
A = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
B = numpy.array([1, 0, 0, 1]) # the first row is class 1, the second row is class 0 ...
M = # Do something
```

This should give me the output:

```
>>M
numpy.array([[2, 3, 4], [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]])
```

Here, row `i` in `M` is the mean for class `i`.

Comment: Are you wedded to using `numpy`?  Working with data and observations is more a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) problem; computing the means (as well other statistics) is a one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment, depending on where you want to go with this, pandas may be more useful. But right now this is still possible with numpy

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
B = numpy.array([1, 0, 0, 1])

class_indicators = B[:, numpy.newaxis] == numpy.unique(B)
mean_operator = numpy.linalg.pinv(class_indicators.astype(float))

means = mean_operator.dot(A)
```

This example works for many classes etc, but as you see, this may be cumbersome

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this using numpy's new [`at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) functionality.

```
A = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
B = numpy.array([1, 0, 0, 1])

u, uinds = numpy.unique(B, return_inverse=True)
M = numpy.zeros((u.shape[0], A.shape[-1]))
numpy.add.at(M, B, A)
M /= numpy.bincount(uinds)[:, None]

M
array([[ 2. ,  3. ,  4. ],
       [ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5]])
```

As mentioned pandas would make this easier:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.DataFrame(A).groupby(B).mean()
     0    1    2
0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  2.5  3.5  4.5
```

Comment: I like `add.at`! However `M[B] += A` shouldn't work with an index array, because the indexing creates a copy, and the addition is swallowed by it.

Comment: Hmm you are right, I think one of the beta's combined the functionality. A thorough reading of the documentation indicates that this is intended, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: In any case, +1 for `add.at`, I really learnt something there!

Comment: Numpy 1.9 adds a `return_counts` kwarg to `np.unique`, so you can skip the call to `np.bincount` and do `u, ucnts = numpy.unique(B, return_counts=True); ... ; M /= ucnts[:, None]`, which is also noticeably faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical grouping problem, which can be solved in a single line using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(B).mean(A)
```